# file ended while scanning use of @\item

Tags: errors, enumerate

My code gives no errors until I write this:

```
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
    \item (a,b) $\ncong$ [c,d),
    \item (a,b) $\ncong$ [c,d], and
    \item [a,b) $\ncong$ [c,d).
\end{enumerate}
```

The error message is "file ended while scanning use of @\item"

I don't know how to fix this.

This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[width=2.00cm, height=2.00cm, left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{commath}
```

`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Try replacing `\item [a,b) $\ncong$ [c,d).` by `\item {} [a,b) $\ncong$ [c,d).`, and, if that does not help, post a complete but minimal document, not just two fragments, since additional issues may arise when others combine them in a way you did not.

Comment: I just checked, this indeed cures the issue (according to what I find). However, personally I'd set all the math in math mode, `\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
    \item $(a,b) \ncong [c,d)$,
    \item $(a,b)\ncong [c,d]$, and
    \item $[a,b) \ncong [c,d)$.
\end{enumerate}`, in which case the issue does not arise. The issue is that `\item` allows for an optional argument that can be passed to it in square brackets, `\item[<option>]`, but you only have an opening `[`, which you need to "hide" from the parser.

Comment: @marmot Would you like to add an answer?

Comment: @CarLaTeX If you say so. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE! At first sight the problem seems a bit mysterious. It stems from the fact that `\item` allows for an optional argument that can be passed to it in square brackets, `\item[<option>]`. You do have an open square bracket after an `\item`, which however does not indicate the beginning of an option. So you need to tell the parser that this is not an option, and one way to achieve this is to add an "empty group" `{}`, i.e. replace

```
\item [a,b) $\ncong$ [c,d).
```

by

```
\item {} [a,b) $\ncong$ [c,d).
```

However, in your very document, there is an even more natural fix. By convention, all math has to go in math mode, so you really might want to add a `$` before the `[`, which then automatically resolves the issue.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[width=2.00cm, height=2.00cm, left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{commath}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
    \item $(a,b) \ncong [c,d)$,
    \item $(a,b)\ncong [c,d]$, and
    \item $[a,b) \ncong [c,d)$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just not to leave the question unanswered

Comment: @CarLaTeX Yes, I just don't know when questions should get marked as a duplicate, which this, at least by some standards, most likely is, or closed as "off-topic because solved in the comments" or just answered. Anyway, if someone else thinks there should not be an answer, I will be happy to remove this post.

Comment: I think the problem here is peculiar, because the OP used `[` not to set the item options but just as text, I think it's a good question (and answer).

Comment: @CarLaTeX I agree with that statement. (I had the same issue many years back, and this issue almost drove me crazy, similarly to having a `*` or `[` after a `\\\` in a matrix or table.) I just do not know if someone answered a very similar question before.